# How to copy data from Pointer to Pointer in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, unmanaged

I am converting a legacy C++ code and need help with memcpy_s equivalent in C#. I need to copy data that is in one pointer to a another pointer as shown in this C++ code.

I tried C++ CopyMemory, Array.Copy and other methods as per google, however none of them seem to be helping. I would like to convert the equivalent in C# of the following code shown below. any help would be highly appreciated.

```
memcpy_s((char*)pDIB + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), bmpHeader.biSizeImage,
            pRawData, bmpHeader.biSizeImage);
```

This code is taking the pointer and adding the size of BITMAPHeader and adding another pointer data to it. I dont see any Marshal.PointerToPointer in C# and not sure how to write this.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't translate code literally. [You wind up with garbage all too often](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us), and the programs that do work are almost always poor. What you need to do to get a good result is fully understand the behaviour of the source program and re-implement that behaviour in the new language, using the structure, libraries, and idioms of that new language to the fullest.

Comment: If you're moving away from C++ it would probably be best to rewrite the code using the C#/.NET ways of doing things instead of trying to do a one-to-one mapping using pointers and such, otherwise you might as well just leave your code in C++.

Comment: For example, I would be quite surprised if the .Net libraries do not already have a bitmap file reader/writer that you can use instead.

Comment: *This code is taking the pointer and adding the size of BITMAPHeader and adding another pointer data to it* --  You need to understand the code at a higher-level.  Your C++ code shows low-level BMP handling in C or C++.  There is no need to go low-level for .NET languages, since handling images and bitmaps should be available in one or more of the .NET classes.

Comment: Looks like you are copying raw image data from a bitmap struct. This data would be stored as a byte array in C#, so use `Array.Copy()`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to worry about pointers in C# everything is managed!

If you're trying to work with bitmap data use the managed [Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.8) class and create the bitmap using a stream set to the raw byte data. Alternatively, you can use the [BitmapSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource?view=netframework-4.8) class.

If you *are* actually still interacting with unmanaged code and trying to get data in and out of that, you can use [GCHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle?view=netframework-4.8) and pinned buffers. But if you are converting something into pure C#, you should be able to ditch the pointers entirely. Just think of them as object instances and architect from that...

Comment: I'd say you have to worry about pointers less. You can still blow a program up with them, it's just harder and less frequent.